# Shifting all elements in an array with one pass and no second array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

I'm trying to figure out how to do a value shift in an array by one value incrementally in Java, without using a second array to store values. Is there a way to just have a couple (1-3ish) of values in memory at a time and shift over everything?

Comment: _"Is there a way to just have a couple (1-3ish) of values in memory at a time and shift over everything?"_ - yes

Comment: Great! I'm glad to hear that. How?

Comment: Like [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Insertion_sort). Each iteration of the outer loop is doing what you want.

Comment: [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) works 'as if' making a complete copy and is usually optimized to not actually do so -- although you can't _guarantee_ this because it's implemented as native code.

Answer (score 0):

**To shift everything in a single pass is actually a single iteration of bubble-sort.**

But, if it works for you, I would recommend the wrapper around java array where you will store additional parameter -> `shift`. With such an implementation, you would achieve great efficiency in array read/write operation and code consumers will not figure out the difference.

The thing is in calculation of the position/index in "real time"

```java
int pos = (index + shift) % n;
```

Full code with method `shift()` is below:

```java
public class Array {

    private int[] arr;
    int n;
    private int shift;

    public Array(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.arr = new int[n];
        shift = 0;              // no shift, so shift is zero
    }

    public void set(int index, int value) {
        if (index >= n) { throw new IllegalArgumentException();  }
        int pos = ( index + shift ) % n;
        arr[pos] = value;
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        if (index >= n) { throw new IllegalArgumentException();  }
        int pos = ( index + shift ) % n;
        return arr[pos];
    }

    public void shift(int places) {
        shift = ( shift + places ) % n;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
            int pos = (index + shift) % n;
            System.out.print(arr[pos] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Array array = new Array(4);
        array.set(0,0); array.set(1,1); array.set(2,2); array.set(3,3);
        array.print();
        // 0 1 2 3

        array.shift(1);
        array.print();
        // 1 2 3 0 
    }
}
```

Comment: This creates the effect of _rotating_ not _shifting_